# htaccess: Force https ONLY on single, sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Let's say I have a sub-directory: /cart

I want visitors who visit /cart to be redirected to https://www.website.com/cart

I do not want visitors who visit /cart/checkout or /cart/catalog, etc. to be redirected. Only for the specific directory /cart.

I attempted to implemented the following in the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^cart$ https://www.website.com/cart/$1 [R,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to have any affect. What is the best approach for this scenario?

Comment: Does it help if you add either `RewriteBase /` before the rules, or change the rule to `RewriteRule ^/cart$...`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$1` here but problem appears to be no trailing slash in your rule when `cart` is a directory. Try this rule as **very first rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule ^cart/?$ https://www.website.com/cart/ [NC,R,L]
```